# correct C casts

Tags: c, casting

I'm not so sure about correct casts, here especially from unsigned int and #defines (whatever type that is) to double.

In this example

```
#define SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM 10

int speed_counter_left;

double result = speed_counter_left / SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM;
```

the result always is 0 when speed_counter_left is < 10.

So I put in some casts:

```
double result = (double) ((double) speed_counter_left / (double) SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM);
```

This is correct, but I think there are too many casts. How can I figure out the correct way with least casts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having one `double` operand should be enough:

```
double result = (double)speed_counter_left / SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM;
```

The cast "*sticks*" closest to `speed_counter_left`. So it's essentially equivalent to:

```
double result = ((double)speed_counter_left) / SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM;
```

---

> and #defines (whatever type that is) to double.

The standard says:

> *6.4.4.1 - 5*
>
> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list
>   in which its value can be represented.

And (for decimal constants without suffixes) the list goes: `int`, `long int`, `long long int`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to cast, make `SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM` a `double` by using `10.0` instead of `10`.

```
#define SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM 10.0

int speed_counter_left;

double result = speed_counter_left / SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM;
```

Comment: Hmm, whilst this would work, the name `SPEEDSENSOR_EDGES_NUM` sounds like it describes an inherently integer quantity...